# Firefox does not play videos on after Ubuntu upgrade

Tags: apt, upgrade, 22.04, firefox, video

A few days ago Ubuntu (22.04 LTS) showed me a message saying I can upgrade my OS (or something along those lines). I click on agree (any button that would let me proceed) and the upgrade took place (without restarting). Along with the upgrade Firefox was also updated to its latest version at the time (119.0). Since then, videos on Twitter play but without sound. On YouTube, Firefox shows me a message saying "To play video, you may need to install the required video codecs" and none of the videos play; I haven't tried other websites but I assume all would have some issues. **Google Chrome** however doesn't have this issue and all videos play without any issues.

I restarted my computer after the upgrade but have the same issue still.

I did the followings and restarted Firefox but none have worked so far:

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras
sudo apt install libavcodec-extra
```

I also learned that by default Firefox is a "snap" package on Ubuntu 22. So I also did the following and installed ffmpeg as a snap package but still have the same issue after restarting Firefox:

```
sudo snap install ffmpeg
```

Could you help me figure out what I should do to fix this issue?

Comment: Install firefox as an APT package. It should fix the issue https://askubuntu.com/q/1399383/124466

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi but I'm looking for a way to fix the issue without having to install Firefox as an APT package. Do you know how to do that? By the way, I think my Firefox should be an APT package by default because I didn't install it manually and it came with Ubuntu

Comment: Ubuntu's default APT package is just the snap version packaged as APT

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi The problem is I have lots of bookmarks and open tabs and other settings that don't want to be gone if I uninstall Firefox and install the APT version. Is there a way to fix this codec issue with the Firefox I have now?

Comment: You can sync your tabs and bookmarks with Firefox Sync. I don't know how to fix this in the snap version of Firefox